# How can we prove that $f^{-1}(q)$ is a closed subset in $M$ given $f:M\to N$ a smooth function between two manifolds and $q\in N$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-functions

I know that, since $\{q\}$ is a closed subset of $N$, $N\setminus\{q\}$ is an open subset of $N$. Since $f$ is smooth, in particular continuous, we could say that $f^{-1}(N\setminus\{q\})$ is an open subset of $M$, but this is just $M\setminus f^{-1}(q)$. So $f^{-1}(q)$ must be a closed subset in $M$.

Is this reasoning correct? I'm not sure if I can say right away that $f^{-1}(N\setminus\{q\})$ is also open. If not, how else would you prove this statement?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: For a continuous map the inverse imagine of any open (respectively closed) set is open (respectively closed).

Comment: @podiki I know that result for functions of the form $f:\Bbb R^m\to\Bbb R^n$. Is it true because $M$ and $N$, rather than being manifolds, are topological spaces?

Comment: It is not true for arbitrary topological spaces. The codomain of the function must be a $T_1$-space (i.e., singletons are closed). In particular, Hausdorff spaces (and therefore manifolds) have this property. Also, only continuity is required, not smoothness (which doesn't even make sense in the pure topological setting).

Comment: @IvoTerek I see, thank you so much!